# Textarea height adjustment according to content size assigned to value

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, textarea

I have a textarea i'm using in my react application. I'm displaying some text in my text area but the problem is when the text is long, textarea won't expand to show the full text.Instead it gives a scroll to scroll down. How can i expand my textarea according to the content size i have set to value of `textarea`

my code is as follows

```
<div className="width_100">

        <textarea className="home_post_text margin_bottom10px" value={this.urlify(postData.heading)}></textarea>

 </div>
```

This is how it shows in my react application. I have to scroll down to see the full text. How can i expand my textarea so it shows the full text.

[image]

Comment: You can show text in `<p>` instead of `<textarea>`.

Comment: Well that's exactly what a `<textarea>` element is supposed to do. Why are you using `<textarea>` in the first place?

Comment: Because the content i get from the backend is multi line content. To get the multilines i'm using textarea

Answer (score 0):

You could use, `div[contenteditable=true]` instead of `textarea`; because `textarea` is supposed to behave like that. If you were to use `textarea` you would have to adjust the element's height at every input, it can easily become a performance killer.

Using `contenteditable` on a `div` on the other hand, permit that you take advantage of the default behavior, which is, to grow the height of the element to fit its contents.

> Bare in mind that `contenteditable` doesn't work well on some older browsers (like `IE10` and below)

Check the working snippet bellow.

```css
div[contenteditable="true"] {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  test
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Implementing a text area component with `contenteditable`

```
<TextArea
    value={myText}
    style={{ 'border': '1px solid grey' }}
    onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)} />
```

**implementation**

```
class TextArea extends React.Component {    
  onChange() {
    var text = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).innerText;
    this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange({
      target: {
        value: text
      }
    });
  }

  render() {    
    const {props} = this;

    return (
      <div
        contentEditable={true}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.value.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>') }}
        onInput={this.onChange.bind(this)}
        onBlur={this.onChange.bind(this)}
        {...props}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: But without the textarea , the text gets displayed in a single line even when it's supposed to go to a new line. I fixed that problem by using a textarea. But having to scroll down to view all the text was the problem.

Comment: If you run my code snippet you get that behavior? If not, you have styling issues.

Comment: contenteditable="true" provides a input like component. What i want is just to display my data and when the data has multiline content, i want to display it in multi lines as well. At the moment it is displayed in a single line.

Comment: @CraZyDroiD I have updated my answer with a simple implementation of what I have briefly described on the answer, alternatively, you could use a third party component or even use facebook's draft-js